# NLA not supported on this PC - need to connect via RDC to server

Tags: windows-10, networking, remote-desktop, windows-server-2008

I have Windows 10 PC as client. It shows "NLA not supported" but all versions of RDC seem current.
"About" in RDC displays Shell & Control versions 10.0.19041, Network Level Authentication not supported, and RDP 10.8 supported.

I need to connect to a Windows 2008 server, and no, turning off the NLA requirement is not an option. (This seems to be the most common guidance from internet "experts".)

Attempting to connect returns the message "The remote computer requires Network Level Authentication, which your computer does not support."

I have two networks connected on this computer. The server is on one of them. I have tried disabling the other network. I have disabled the firewall. I have turned off my anti-virus and Acronis protection products. I have ensured that I have outgoing ports open for RDC. I have reviewed services and made sure that all the Remote Desktop related services were running. I even tried a system restore a couple of weeks back in case a recent Windows update was responsible. I setup the firewall to allow the RD programs through. I have researched as many search keyword variations as I can come up with only to find that every new search finds pages I have already read. I did find one suggesting a conflict with SMBv1, so I made sure that was disabled. Nothing changed.

My main confusion is why an up to date Windows 10 system does not support NLA? If it is a matter of updating, then how do I do that / where do I get it? What else can I try to get this to work?

Getting NLA to work / be supported on this computer is the ideal, but I keep finding only variations of "it may be out of date, just turn NLA requirement on the server off".

Comment: NLA is a standard component of Windows since Vista (or even further back, not sure). It ought to work. But: check that your PC's time is setup correctly (timezone, DST and the actual time). If your time is more than 3 minutes off from the time on the server Kerberos authentication won't work and because of that NLA won't work either.  
Could also be that your PC has correct time, but server is off. Last but not least: Your client must be in same domain (or forest) as server. Else Kerberos (and NLA) don't work either.

Comment: @Tonny, if it is an issue with synchronized settings between client and host, then why do I get the About message "Network Level Authentication not supported" only opening RPC? It has not attempted any connection, so I do not see how anything related to the server could be related. If it would attempt to connect but errored trying to authorize, and About said "[NLA] supported", then that would make more sense. Nonetheless, I will check all of those.